# Declaring my php array outside of my foreach loop is not working

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

Ok I have searched everywhere for this answer and I have come up empty or solutions that don't seem to be working unless I'm not doing something correctly. I am using php.

I have a data set pulled from a database with this:

```
try {
$repinfo = $db->query("SELECT * FROM reps WHERE chamber='senate';");    
$encoded = $repinfo->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
} catch (Exception $e) {
    print_r("You failed");
}
```

Then I have a foreach loop that is iterating through the data

```
$member=array();
foreach ($encoded as $key=>$value) {
$var1 = $value["something"];
$var2 = $value["something2"];
$var3 = $value["something3"]; //etc.
```

then I'm trying to push these into an array:

```
$member[$var1] = array( //I want $var1 to also be the id for each of the elements in the main array
"var1" => $var1,
"var2" => $var2,
"var3" => $var3
);
} //closing foreach loop here
```

I have declared the array before the foreach as instructed by other sources. I get the same error that I can't use a scalar value as an array!!
When I declare the array inside the loop I just end up reseting the array each time. I'm trying to create a specific key for each of the items in the array using a specific id that I'm pulling from the database.
Can someone help me figure out how to do this? I feel like I have tried everything!

Comment: Have you searched for that error? I can guarantee that you will find what the problem is.

Comment: Can you post a `var_dump($encoded);`?

Comment: I think it would be best to post your entire code snippet and tell us which line exactly is throwing the error. Upon initial inspection I think the issue is that the data type of $value is not an array and you are attempting to use it as an array.